# Shorewall configuration : providers and LAN

Tags: iptables, firewall, nat, lan

Hi all and thanks in advance for the answers.

Currently, I have different providers configured in shorewall. I'll will probably have to change one of them. The problem is I won't have any Public IP like I already have but a private LAN. I'm not sure I will be able to masquerade like I'm doing :

```
#####################################################################
#INTERFACE              SOURCE           ADDRESS
# Ensure that traffic originating on the firewall and redirected via
# packet marks always has the source IP address corresponding to the
# interface that it is routed out of.
# See http://shorewall.net/MultiISP.html#Example1
eth0                    eth2      
eth1                    eth2     
eth0                    eth3             
eth1                    eth3             
eth0                    eth4             
eth1                    eth4
```

eth0 and eth1 are providers with public IPs.
eth2, eth3 and eth4 are private LANs.
What happen if eth1 becomes a private LAN ?

Thanks

Just to be clear :
If I have a WAN configured in a cisco router in bridge mode, I'll just need to configure the Public IP in the shorewall providers and masquerade to different LANs.
But if I have a WAN configured in a cisco router with NAT, can I just configure the LAN IP in the shorewall providers and masquerade to different LANs ? I know it's stupid because you have double NAT but sometimes you can't decide :/